# IE ppi limit for jpg images

Tags: image, internet-explorer, browser, jpeg, resolution

I deal with high resolution images and sometimes put them up on the web.  One issue I've come across is that IE can't (or won't) deal with high resolution jpg images; it won't even try to show them, whereas other browsers will.  One obscure post I found mentioned that he heard from so-and-so that the limit was 150 ppi.

I can't seem to find the reference for this anywhere, and I imagine that other useful image rendering rules for IE could be found near any official documentation.  Any pointers on where this limitation might be documented?

EDIT:  This image is at 300 ppi.  View this in chrome or FF, it displays.  In IE(at least IE 8, which I'm using) it won't display.

[image: Sample High-resolution image]

Comment: The problem is likely bound to the pixel size of the image, not the resolution.

Comment: @Brad For same-size images, when I take the resolution down to 72, it displays correctly.  You can have giant pictures, as long as the resolution isn't too high.

Comment: Yes, because you are changing the pixel dimension size of the image...

Comment: I'm assuming you mean by either css styling or inline width and height attributes.  I've done a bit of experimenting with this, and the same picture won't show whether you define width or height in any way, or don't define it.  It won't show if you set the attributes to exactly the dimension saved by Photoshop, it won't show no matter what other changes I make until I change the ppi. That has been true for images 1"X1" as well as 20"X20". It's definitely down to the resolution, not the dimensions. There may be other rules for dimension, and that's also something I'd like to know. S'why I asked

Comment: What I am trying to explain is that dimensions in anything other than pixels are irrelevant. Any scaling done to match another dimension (such as inches) is all just virtual.  Pixel size is all that matters.  Who cares if your image is 1"x1" if it is at 1200ppi... you have a 1200x1200 pixel image.  If you had a 12"x12" image at 100 ppi, you also have a 1200x1200 pixel image.  Those two image sizes, as far as memory usage and processing is concerned, are identical in dimension.

Comment: Right, I get the theory behind what you're saying, but it's pretty obvious that, though ppi is "just virtual", it isn't imaginary or irrelevant to this question.  A 4" image won't display in IE at 250 ppi but a 14" image with 100 ppi will display.  Pixel dimensions are the same, as you say.  I'm just trying to figure out where any of this may be documented for IE so I can figure out exactly what all their limitations are.  It's obvious they do things differently--other browsers couldn't care less about ppi, but IE does.  Who knows, maybe they don't use inches, but some IE unit--PPIEU.

Comment: Can you post an example file that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yep, I inserted an arbitrary image in at 300 ppi.  This isn't one that requires high resolution, but it demonstrates the IE limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, your problem has nothing to do with the resolution of the image.

The problem here is that you are trying to display an image in CYMK color-space.  Many browsers (such as IE 8 and below) don't like this.

You should be using RGB for all of your web images.  You can convert in Photoshop by clicking `Image` -> `Mode` -> `RGB Color`.

As proof of this concept, here is your original image converged to RGB color-space at 1,000 PPI:

[image: RGB Example]

And, a screenshot of this working in IE 8:

[image: IE8 Screenshot]

Comment: Well, my faith in GIMP has lessened considerably.  I know that CMYK is for print, not for web, but GIMP says right on the top when I open the image that it is RGB.  Perhaps it was just converting to RGB automatically when I changed anything.  In any case, thanks!

Comment: @Indigenuity, GIMP tells you RGB because that's all it knows.  GIMP is not capable of working with images in CMYK.  When you open a CMYK image, it is converted to RGB.  There are some less-direct methods to export to CMYK from GIMP, but no native support.  See also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CMYK_support_in_The_GIMP#About_CMYK_color_and_Gimp